# screen flickering with every keyboard stroke in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 issues:

1. the screen is getting rebuilt every time I type something, it was working fine, and not sure what happened!

[image]

2. when I click send,  a message will be sent even if the `TextField` is empty. It basically sends the last message. The text is being cleared but still getting sent.

[image]

here is my code

```
class ChatGroupLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatGroupLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatGroupLayout> createState() => _ChatGroupLayoutState();
}

class _ChatGroupLayoutState extends State<ChatGroupLayout> {
  final fieldText = TextEditingController();

  void clearText() {
    fieldText.clear();
  }

  var _enterdMessage;

  void _sendMessage() async {
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .get();

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groupsChat')
        .doc('groupsChat')
        .collection('P1HSu0cjsQSyIKZ7ZiX6a74rwzU2')
        .add({
      'text': _enterdMessage.trim(),
      'time': Timestamp.now(),
      'userid': user?.uid,
      'displayname': userData['displayname']
    });
    clearText();
  }

  static final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: ListTile(
            onTap: () => showBarModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => const GroupDetailsScreen()),
            tileColor: Colors.black,
            title: const Center(child: Text('Group Chat')),
            subtitle: const Center(child: Text('323 in this Group')),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ChatGroupScreen(),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 0, top: 5),
                    child: TextField(
                      key: _formKey,
                      controller: fieldText,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _enterdMessage = value;
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.attach_file,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.black,
                        hintText: 'type a message',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_enterdMessage.trim().isEmpty) {
                        return null;
                      } else {
                        _sendMessage();
                        clearText();
                      }
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          //TextInput
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i removed the setState() from the OnChanged() now it doesn't flicker on typing, however still do on sending the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do: Completely remove the onChanged property of the textField. It is not needed. You can get the current text in the textField from its controller. And in the onPressed function of the icon button check if controller.text is not equal to "" and if yes call the _sendMessage function.
updatedCode:

```
class ChatGroupLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatGroupLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatGroupLayout> createState() => _ChatGroupLayoutState();
}

    class _ChatGroupLayoutState extends State<ChatGroupLayout> {
      final fieldText = TextEditingController();

      void clearText() {
        fieldText.clear();
      }

      void _sendMessage() async {
        final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user?.uid)
            .get();

        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('groupsChat')
            .doc('groupsChat')
            .collection('P1HSu0cjsQSyIKZ7ZiX6a74rwzU2')
            .add({
          'text': fieldText.text.trim(),
          'time': Timestamp.now(),
          'userid': user?.uid,
          'displayname': userData['displayname']
        });
      }

      static final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              title: ListTile(
                onTap: () => showBarModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => const GroupDetailsScreen()),
                tileColor: Colors.black,
                title: const Center(child: Text('Group Chat')),
                subtitle: const Center(child: Text('323 in this Group')),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ChatGroupScreen(),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 0, top: 5),
                        child: TextField(
                          key: _formKey,
                          controller: fieldText,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.attach_file,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.black,
                            hintText: 'type a message',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                width: 0,
                                style: BorderStyle.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (fieldText.text != "") {
                            _sendMessage();
                            clearText();
                          }
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
              //TextInput
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: hey, i tried your code and it's sending empty strings to Firestore

Comment: Try making the onPressed function async and putting await in front of _senMessage() call

Comment: Because the problem might be that because _sendMessage() is async and currently not awaited clearText() is carried out before _sendMessage() is completed.

Comment: thnx man, that worked, for the second issue, and idea about the first one ? the screen is getting rebuilt when the message is sent

Comment: What's the problem with the screen getting rebuilt. Isn't that necessary so the textField can be cleared?

Comment: the whole screen is getting rebuilt including the message already been sent

Comment: check this https://s7.gifyu.com/images/flick1cd2a72c8f45b828.gif

Comment: Don't the old messages need to be rebuilt as well, because they have to be pushed up slightly so the new message fits below?

Comment: i understand all that, but this is different , this might bee more clearer
https://s7.gifyu.com/images/loading.gif

Comment: The mistake should be in your ChatGroupScreen Widget. For me it looks like your using a FutureBuilder there, displaying an empty chat when the new messages is being loaded and the complete chat again when it is loaded. That produces the flickering. So you have to not display an empty chat while the new message is being loaded but rather display the old chat and everything should look fine.

Comment: Actually i just got it !  your were not to far, it was of course my bad i accidentally had a stream builder in ChatGroupScreen when i was already receiving the variable as argument which leads the screen to be redrawn again ! .. thnx man